# firefox addon installation issue

Tags: firefox-addon

After worked on many small addon i want to put those add on on my server so that people can download it and use it so that i can get the feedback from the people ..but when i am downloading it from my server(it is a xpi file) getting following error..

```
Firefox could not install the file at 

http://abhimanyu.homeunix.com/Work/abhiman_2k5@yahoo.com.xpi

because: Install script not found
-204
```

but when i m putting these files manually in the path it works fine..After fiddling many hours couldn't figure it out whats the problem ...please help me.

Answer (score 1):

I assume that you are letting the users download your add-on through some install button.

Unfortunately, its not as simple as pointing the browser to the xpi file on the server's file system. Below, I have pasted the script that installs Omture when the user presses on the "Download Omture" button on the add-on's [website](http://www.omture.com/) which you could also find using firebug.

```
function installExt()
{
var url="omture_current.xpi";

InstallTrigger.install({
                     "Omture": { URL: url,
                     toString : function() { return this.URL; } } });
return false;
}
```